# Is it possible to execute "cout" by order?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

Is it possible to get the raw output as shown but with specific order(from bottom to top)?

```
cout<<R"(programming )";sleep(10); cout<<R"(
          newbie at  )";sleep(5); cout<<R"(
            i'm      )"; sleep(1);


output:  programming------>printed third at the first line
           newbie at------->printed second at the second line
            i'm--------->printed first at the third line
```

Note: I don't mean reversing the output.

edit: as I guess the simple trick is to set their colour to black which will make them "disappear" and then by using nested for loop I can move through lines and change the colour of their one by one to white again  with delay but i dont have an idea about how to do it practically

Comment: Threads with timers would do the job.

Comment: thanks for commenting.....any good books or resources to learn thread usage in CPP?

Comment: To my knowledge, no. `cout` doesn't control the output line position.

Comment: what is difference between reversing the order and getting output in opposite order?

Comment: well....controlling  the  output line position is a handy thing

Comment: Note that `cout` (and the basic library streams in general)  is really, really stupid. It has to handle a lot of different cases and is bound by the lowest common denominator of all of those cases.

Comment: @user4581301 noted ✓ .....thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    auto print_first_line = std::async(std::launch::async, []() {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(6s);
        std::cout << "programming\n" << std::flush;
    });
    auto print_second_line = std::async(std::launch::async, []() {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(3s);
        std::cout << "newbie at\n" << std::flush;
    });
    auto print_third_line = std::async(std::launch::async, []() {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        std::cout << "i'm\n" << std::flush;
    });

    print_first_line.wait();
    print_second_line.wait();
    print_third_line.wait();

    return 0;
}
```

As stated in the comments, it is not possible to control `std::cout` in this way. But it is possible to use threads to control the timing for you. This is a quick & dirty example of using `std::async` from `<future>` to multi-thread your print statements.

The first argument to `std::async` explicitly tells it to launch asynchronously as it can launch without creating a new thread. The second argument is a lambda with the sleep timer and the print statement.

It is worth noting that you will likely need an additional compiler argument. My current testing is in the WSL (Debian), so the compile command I'm using is `clang++ -Wall -Wextra -pthread main.cpp` where `-pthread` is the argument enabling multi-threading. For your platform it may be different.

As suggested, this scenario might be better served with a more generic function; something like `delay_print()`. Here's a possible implementation.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

void delay_print(const std::chrono::duration<std::int64_t> &time,
                 std::string message)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(time);
    std::cout << message << std::flush;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    std::array<int, 4> seconds{7, 4, 2, 1};
    std::array<std::string, 4> phrases{"How\n", "Now\n", "Brown\n", "Cow\n"};

    auto print_line_01 =
        std::async(std::launch::async, &delay_print,
                   std::chrono::seconds(seconds[0]), phrases[0]);
    auto print_line_02 =
        std::async(std::launch::async, &delay_print,
                   std::chrono::seconds(seconds[1]), phrases[1]);
    auto print_line_03 =
        std::async(std::launch::async, &delay_print,
                   std::chrono::seconds(seconds[2]), phrases[2]);
    auto print_line_04 =
        std::async(std::launch::async, &delay_print,
                   std::chrono::seconds(seconds[3]), phrases[3]);

    print_line_01.wait();
    print_line_02.wait();
    print_line_03.wait();
    print_line_04.wait();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might even create function/lambda `delay_print`.

Comment: That'd be a better, more generalized solution.

Comment: that did a job, thanks a bunch, but now I edited my question and can you quick-check if it is possible?

Comment: If you're just talking about the spacing, you just need to add the spacing. The edit doesn't change much of anything. I'm implementing the `delay_print()` that was suggested.

Comment: @sweenish no I'm not talking about spacing ...Ummm this code prints "I'm"  at the first line

Comment: than "newbie at" on the second line and "programming" at the third line...

Comment: but I'm struggling at printing it without reversing but with same delay.. as indicated

Comment: My code does exactly that. The delays are a bit different, but it prints "i'm", followed by "newbie at" followed by "programming"

Comment: sorry...I'm really bad at explaining.. first thing I want to print is "I'm" but on the third line than "newbie at" on top of "i'm" on second line an at last "programming" but on top of all of them on first line...

Comment: If you want your text printed in the same order, but want it to write upwards, you'll need something like ncurses. Terminals don't work like that out-of-the-box. You'll essentially be creating a CLI "GUI".

Comment: yeap just checked and "ncurses" is what I need... I guess I have to bang my head on my desk for more hours